# How to set identify tool to identify from visible layers as a default when starting ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How to set identify tool to identify from visible layers as default when starting ArcGIS without the need to change it from top-most layer to visible layer each time stating arcmap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Customize (menu) - ArcMap Options - General - Tools - Default Layer for Identify tool and select Visible layers.